# scalar and vector kernels in OpenCl

Tags: vector, kernel, opencl, scalar

I'm reading this paper http://eprints.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/1694/1/miniMD_opencl.pdf about a mini molecular dynamics application using OpenCl. The code is located here.
I got stuck with how kernels are implemented. What I don't understand is this

```
#if defined(SCALAR_KERNELS)
__kernel void f_clear(
    __global float* f,
    __const int nall) {

    for (unsigned i = get_global_id(0)+1; i <= nall; i += get_global_size(0)) {
        const int i4 = i << 2;
        f[i4+0] = 0.0f;
        f[i4+1] = 0.0f;
        f[i4+2] = 0.0f;
        f[i4+3] = 0.0f;
    }

}
#elif defined(VECTOR_KERNELS)
__kernel __attribute__((vec_type_hint(float4)))
void f_clear(
    __global float4* f,
    __const int nall) {

    const float4 zeroes = (float4) (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    for (unsigned i = get_global_id(0)+1; i <= nall; i += get_global_size(0)) {
        f[i] = zeroes;
    }

}
#endif
```

Is suppose `VECTOR_KERNELS` and `SCALAR_KERNELS` correspond to GPU and MIC devices but not sure.
Does that have something to do with MIMD SIMD instructions or multi-core and vector programming?
Also is there a real advantage of using vector type now days?
Finaly, I really can't figure what the two for loops do and the purpose of them.
Why not just do `f[get_global_id(0)]` ?
Thanks,
Éric.

Answer (score 3):

Scalar and vector are just different ways of performing the same thing in OpenCL.
But **vectors are the way to go** since they should be optimized better by the compiler (either CPU or GPU/FPGA). This way the compiler can naturally eploit the SIMD units. So, if it is possible and easyer for you, use them.

As Austin said, both loops clean the global memory size of `nall`.

However looking at the code is very unefficient. The workitems in the same workgroup are accessing completely different global memory zones, breaking coalescence. It will be much better just by (as you said):

```
__kernel __attribute__((vec_type_hint(float4)))
void f_clear(
    __global float4* f) {
    f[get_global_id(0)] = (float4) (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

And launching this kernel with the proper global size (`global_size = nall`) and let the compiler decide the local workgroup size.

PS: If I would have to do it, I prefer to call a clEnqueueWriteBuffer and clean the memory from CPU. Since it can be done in parallel to other kernel executions.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices like AMD, ATI, and Intel are really good about supporting vector types.  These vectors are SIMD and is faster to use it if possible.  NVIDIA doesn't seem very good (at least all the ones I've tested) at supporting vectors in OpenCL.

Both the loops appear to clear a chunk of global memory of size `nall`.